# How to download start script in domain from admin to managed server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, weblogic, weblogic12c

Do the managed server can download start scripts in bin folder from admin server without node manager?

for instance, the end user had been created domain for while, now, they want to have more features so they run Weblogic tool wizard to extend this domain on admin server, according the template to be extended, more application will be added in config.xml and more Java -d startup parameters will be added in start scripts(e.g. startweblogic.cmd/setStartupEnv.cmd).

We know that every time when starting managed server, all configurations, applications will be downloaded from admin to managed server automatically in the domain , but the start scripts in bin folder are exceptions, this is to say, after extending the domain on admin node, the startup script are not sync-ed with managed nodes but all others are sync-ed.

I don't have node manager available, so is there any way to download the startup script from admin to managed node, or another approach to implement on managed server quickly?

Comment: After you extended the domain, do you have `startManagedWebLogic.cmd` in your bin folder? That's the script the nodemanager would use to start managed servers AND the script you would use to manually start managed servers.

Comment: but my managed server on different machine with admin server

Comment: Log into that machine and run `startManagedWebLogic.cmd managed_server_name admin_url` to start the server without the nodemanager